# EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STARTED and EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STOPPED events are fired only when partitions are coming to the node

Tags: java, ignite

I'm trying to find out if it's a bug, a feature, or am I doing something wrong...

So, using Ignite 2.15.0, listening to the local node events in my Ignite Service:

```
ignite.events().localListen((Event evt) -> {
    System.out.println("Ignite event: " + evt.name());
    return true;

  }, EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STARTED, 
       EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STOPPED, 
       EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_PART_UNLOADED);
```

I have a PARTITIONED cache with backup count = 1, and the rebalancing events are actually partially working as expected:

- When another node is dropping from the cluster, i.e. partitions are coming in to my node, I see `EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STARTED` and `EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STOPPED` events, i.e. all works as expected.
- But when ***another*** node is ***joining*** the cluster, then on ***my*** node I see plenty of the `EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_PART_UNLOADED` events, but never the `EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STARTED/STOPPED` ones. However that's a rebalance too, aren't the started/stopped events expected to come in as well?

Hope the above makes sense... Thanks in advance!